# Redis zrangebyscore and zincrby under high concurrency

Tags: node.js, redis, fastify

I am facing concurrency problem with redis, my API is build on Nodejs Fastify and i am using fastify-redis in my API call.

I am using two simple methods of redis **ZRANGEBYSCORE** and **ZINCRBY**

The problem is under high concurrency **ZINCRBY** is executed late which results into giving me same value on multiple request.

How can i prevent this under high concurrency is there any method to lock the KEY which was previously executed.

Here is the example of my code

```
numbers = await redis.zrangebyscore(
            `user:${req.query.key}:${state}`, //key
            0, // min value
            50, // max value
            "LIMIT",
            0, // offset
            1 // limit
        );

if (numbers.length > 0) {
        await redis.zincrby(`user:${req.query.key}:${state}`, 1, numbers[0]);
        res.send(numbers[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't concurrency per se, it's that you have a series of operations that need to be atomic and you haven't done anything to ensure that.

Redis has facilities to try to ensure atomicity, as described [here](https://redis.io/topics/transactions). In your case, since the value from the first operation is used in the second, you couldn't do a simple `MULTI` and `EXEC`. You'd have to instead `WATCH` the key and then retry the operation if it aborted.

The simpler, and recommended approach, though, is just to put your above code into a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval), where it can be executed on the server as a single atomic operation.

Comment: So if i create a lua script and use these commands form lua script it will ensure that zincrby is executed and all the series of operations in atomic way?

Comment: Also do i just need to run MULTI command on ZINCRBY or in a series... one more thing zrangebyscore will return me a value which i will increment, so in a multi command how will i run that? A little help would really clear my concepts

Comment: @AmanullahTanweer: Right, you couldn't just use `MULTI`. You'd have to `WATCH` the key and retry the operation if it aborted. But instead just translate your above code into a Lua script and use `EVAL`. That will make the whole operation atomic.